# Why are Mercurial backouts in one branch affecting other branches?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, branch, dvcs, three-way-merge

This is a difficult situation to explain, so bear with me. I have a Mercurial repository with 2 main branches, *default* and *dev*.

Work is usually done in a named branch off of *dev* (a feature branch). There may be many feature branches at any one time. Once work is completed in that branch, it is merged back into *dev*.

When the time comes to prepare a release, another named branch is created off of *dev* (a release branch). Sometimes it is necessary to exclude entire features from a release. If that is the case, the merge changeset from where the feature branch was merged into *dev* is backed out of the new release branch.

Once a release branch is ready to be released, it is merged into *default* (so *default* always represents the state of the code in production). Work continues as normal on the *dev* branch and feature branches.

The problem occurs when the time comes to do another release, including the feature that was backed out in the previous release. A new release branch is created as normal (off of *dev*). This new release branch now contains the feature that was backed out of the previous release branch (since the backout was performed on the release branch, and the merge changeset remains on the *dev* branch).

This time, when the release branch is ready for release and is merged into *default*, any changes that were backed out as a result of the merge backout in the previous release branch are not merged into *default*. Why is this the case? Since the new release branch contains all of the feature branch changesets (nothing has been backed out), why does the *default* branch not receive all of these changesets too?

If all of the above is difficult to follow, here's a screenshot from TortoiseHg that shows the basic problem. "branch1" and "branch2" are feature branches, "release" and "release2" are the release branches:

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I believe the problem is that merges work differently than you think. You write

> Since the new release branch contains all of the feature branch changesets (nothing has been backed out), why does the default branch not receive all of these changesets too?

When you merge two branches, it's wrong to think of it as applying all changes from one branch onto another branch. So the `default` branch does not "receive" any changesets from `release2`. I know this is how we normally think of merges, but it's inaccurate.

What really happens when you merge two changesets is the following:

1. Mercurial finds the common ancestor for the two changesets.
2. For each file that differ between the two changesets Mercurial runs a [*three-way merge* algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(revision_control)) using the ancestor file, the file in the first changeset and the file in the second changeset.

In your case, you are merging revision 11 and 12. The least common ancestor is revision 8. This means that Mercurial will run a three-way merge between files from there revisions:

- **Revision 8:** no backout
- **Revision 11:** feature branch has been backed out
- **Revision 12:** no backout

In a three-way merge, a change always trumps no change. Mercurial sees that the files have been changed between 8 and 11 and it sees no change between 8 and 12. So it uses the changed version from revision 11 in the merge. This applies for any three-way merge algorithm. The full merge table looks like this where `old`, `new`, ... are the content of matching hunks in the three files:

```
ancestor  local  other -> merge
old       old    old      old (nobody changed the hunk)
old       old    new      new (they changed the hunk)
old       new    old      new (you changed the hunk)
old       new    new      new (hunk was cherry picked onto both branches)
old       foo    bar      <!> (conflict, both changed hunk but differently)
```

I'm afraid that a [merge changeset shouldn't be backed out](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Backout#Backout_of_a_Merge_Changeset) at all because of this surprising merge behavior. Mercurial 2.0 and later will abort and complain if you try to backout a merge.

In general, one can say that the three-way merge algorithm assumes that **all change is good**. So if you merge `branch1` into `dev` and then later undo the merge with a backout, then the merge algorithm will think that the state is "better" than before. This means that you cannot just re-merge `branch1` into `dev` at a later point to get the backed-out changes back.

What you can do is to use a "dummy merge" when you merge into `default`. You simply merge and always keep the changes from the release branch you're merging into `default`:

```
$ hg update default
$ hg merge release2 --tool internal:other -y
$ hg revert --all --rev release2
$ hg commit -m "Release 2 is the new default"
```

That will side-step the problem and force `default` be just like `release2`. This assumes that absolutely no changes are made on `default` without being merged into a release branch.

If you must be able to make releases with skipped features, then the "right" way is to not merge those features at all. Merging is a strong commitment: you tell Mercurial that the merge changeset now has all the good stuff from both its ancestors. As long as Mercurial wont let you [pick your own base revision when merging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9430810/110204), the three-way merge algorithm wont let you change your mind about a backout.

What you can do, however, is to *backout the backout*. This means that you re-introduce the changes from your feature branch onto your release branch. So you start with a graph like

```
release: ... o --- o --- m1 --- m2
                        /      /
feature-A:   ... o --- o      /
                             /
feature-B:  ... o --- o --- o
```

You now decided that the A feature was bad and you backout the merge:

```
release: ... o --- o --- m1 --- m2 --- b1
                        /      /
feature-A:   ... o --- o      /
                             /
feature-B:  ... o --- o --- o
```

You then merge another feature into your release branch:

```
release: ... o --- o --- m1 --- m2 --- b1 --- m3
                        /      /             /
feature-A:   ... o --- o      /             /
                             /             /
feature-B:  ... o --- o --- o             /
                                         /
feature-C:  ... o --- o --- o --- o --- o
```

If you now want to re-introduce the A feature, then you can backout `b1`:

```
release: ... o --- o --- m1 --- m2 --- b1 --- m3 --- b2
                        /      /             /
feature-A:   ... o --- o      /             /
                             /             /
feature-B:  ... o --- o --- o             /
                                         /
feature-C:  ... o --- o --- o --- o --- o
```

We can add the deltas to the graph to better show what changes where and when:

```
                     +A     +B     -A     +C     --A
release: ... o --- o --- m1 --- m2 --- b1 --- m3 --- b2
```

After this second backout, you can merge again with `feature-A` in case new changesets have been added there. The graph you're merging looks like:

```
release: ... o --- o --- m1 --- m2 --- b1 --- m3 --- b2
                        /      /             /
feature-A:   ... o -- a1 - a2 /             /
                             /             /
feature-B:  ... o --- o --- o             /
                                         /
feature-C:  ... o --- o --- o --- o --- o
```

and you merge `a2` and `b2`. The common ancestor will be `a1`. This means that the only changes you'll need to consider in the three-way merge are those between `a1` and `a2` and `a1` and `b2`. Here `b2` already have the bulk of the changes "in" `a2` so the merge will be small.

Comment: Another way of thinking about it is that you took a copy of something (last common ancestor before the branching), and gave those copies to two different people. Now, one of those people does something to his copy, and when you later on want to reconcile the two copies back into one, you have the case of "he did something to his copy" and "that other guy did nothing", Mercurial will happily take the changes that was done on one branch and apply them, regardless of what they are.

Comment: Martin - excellent explanation, will learn and smite in stone. What advice do you have for the unfortunate, who **must make release** with skipped features (if backout is evil, as we see)

Comment: @LazyBadger: thanks for the comment. I've tried to give some advice about handling this.

Answer (score 0):

Martin's answer is, as usual, on the money, but I just wanted to add my 2p.

Another way of thinking about this is that backout doesn't remove anything, it adds the reverse change.

So when you merge you're not doing:

```
Branch after changes <-> Branch before changes => Result with changes
```

you're doing:

```
Branch after changes <-> Branch after changes with removal of changes => Result with changes removed.
```

Basically the first release was done badly. It would be better to cherry-pick the features into the release, than include everything and cherry-pick features out. [Graft](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#graft) may help you here, but I've not tried using it in anger yet to know all the pitfalls.

Comment: "It would be better to cherry-pick the features into the release, than include everything and cherry-pick features out" - almost impossible in real-life with reasonable long release-cycle

Comment: Granted - you're not going to cherry pick every changeset. That would be a sure fire way of going insane. Pick your branch point carefully, and don't let the unwanted features into your release. Cherry pick after that.

Comment: If my release have 10-20 features AND in parallel same amount of bugfixes (also mergeset in default) - it's real numbers - cherry-picking will become russian roulette

Comment: Your 2p is worth it for the clarification on what a backout is. Keeping in mind it *adds* the reverse change is a key point.