# Mercurial: Branch specific changes keep coming back after dummy merge

Tags: mercurial, merge

I have a mercurial repository with two permanent branches, default and UAT. Every once in a while, we deploy (promote) a new version of our application to the UAT environment and we do this by merging a stable default commit across to the UAT branch. Occasionally things will get bug-fixed in the UAT branch, and these bug-fixes get merged back  to default.

On the UAT branch I need to change a few things for deployment purposes - connection strings and various environmental settings. What I tried to do was to make these change in the UAT branch and commit them (all as one commit) right after having merged default into UAT. I then dummy-merged this one commit back onto default - the thinking being that because default now has this commit in its ancestry future bugfix merges from UAT onto default will not try to redo these UAT-specific changes.

However things have not gone as smoothly as I had hoped. Starting with the dummy-merged commit onto default,  I've tried both of the following scenarios:

```
1) Make a few more commits to default and then "promote" to UAT (merge default onto UAT)
2) Make a bugfix on UAT and "backport" it to default (merge UAT onto default)
```

In between running #1 and #2 I've stripped everything out so that both scenarios start from the same point.

What I'm seeing is that depending on the last direction merged I still need to inspect the changed files after doing one or the other merge and revert - sometimes the merge tries to put the default configurations into UAT and sometimes the UAT configurations into merge.

If I revert the configuration changes and commit the merge, then future merges in the same direction behave properly, but the minute I go in the other direction, the merge again puts the wrong configurations into the files.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

I believe the problem is similar to the problem in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9500399/110204): merging doesn't work the way you think it works. Merging is only a question of comparing file-states, it's **not** a matter of applying changes from one branch onto another.

Your starting point is a history like this:

```
UAT:      ... x --- y --- z
                           \
default:  ..... a --- b --- c
```

where `x` and `y` contain the config settings for UAT and `b` is the dummy merge with no config settings. So the files in `b` look like they did in `a` — they were dummy merged.

If you now make a new change on `default` that you want to promote to UAT, you'll work with:

```
UAT:      ... x --- y 
                     \
default:  ..... a --- b --- c
```

The merge is between `y` and `c`. It's a degenerate merge where the common ancestor is `y` itself. This means that all changes between `b` and `c` will "win" in the three-way merge. The table for how hunks are merged in a three-way merge is:

```
ancestor  local  other -> merge
old       old    old      old (nobody changed the hunk)
old       old    new      new (they changed the hunk)
old       new    old      new (you changed the hunk)
old       new    new      new (hunk was cherry picked onto both branches)
old       foo    bar      <!> (conflict, both changed hunk but differently)
```

Note that the merge result doesn't depend on the "direction" of the merge: the table is symmetric with regard to the `local` and `other` columns. Here, both `ancestor` and `local` is `y`, and `other` is `c`. So the table becomes:

```
ancestor  local  other -> merge
old       old    new      new (they changed the hunk)
```

You can see that the merge result always contains the `new` change that was made in `c`.

It's not important that the merge was degenerate. Assuming you have a new commit on UAT and that this commit doesn't touch the config strings, then you'll get the same behavior when you merge (in either direction, merges are symmetric).

**The normal solution** to this problem is to externalize the config strings. Put them somewhere outside of version control — environment variables, an unversioned config file, etc. If you can, then put a config file under version control as a *template*. You then create an unversioned config file for the UAT branch that includes the version controlled config file. You override settings as needed in this unversioned config file.

Comment: In the short term, I'm restricted to having my maintainer deploy our app manually from his machine. He's only got one clone because it's an older web app and changing IIS folder settings is a mission. I'd really like to enable him to use a workflow where all he needs to do is merge from default, rebuild and deploy, with the ability to migrate bug-fixes back to default for later releases. If I never merge UAT back to default, but instead transplant the bugfixes back, I think that will work right? This becomes a problem though if there are a lot of bugfix commits...

Comment: Maybe you could just let the UAT settings be committed (to make it easy for your maintainer) and then modify (but don't commit) them locally? You'll need to shelve the changes before a merge and use `-X` to exclude them when committing (the [exclude extension](https://bitbucket.org/aragost/exclude) can help a bit).

Comment: That's basically what he's doing at the moment - shelving and unshelving as necessary. Unfortunately it's not seamless, and as we add more environments (e.g. production) then he has to deal with multiple shelves or mq, which is not ideal (where 'ideal' is the apparently unobtainable workflow I describe above :) ). I guess we will try the transplant approach for now and see how that goes...

Comment: @TerenceLewis: I suggested that you moved the burden of maintaining shelves from the maintainer to yourself. Transplanting is of course also an option — but then you've almost stopped using version control and gone back to just maintaining a bunch of patch files :-)

Comment: @MartinGeisler: I just wanted to thank you for all the thoughtful and complete answers you give about hg here on SO. Thanks, deeply appreciated :-)